# how to junit test on restTemplate?

Tags: java, resttemplate, junit5

I have a problem to mock restTemplate with Mockito

code want to be test:

```java
public class Feature{
 public static String getfeature(String url){
     RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
     String xml = "\"feature\": 1";
     String json = restTemplate.postForObject(url, xml, String.class);
     return json;
}
}
```

junit code:

```
@Mock
RestTemplate restTemplate=mock(RestTemplate.class);
@Test
public void testGetfeature(){
string testResponse= "\"feature\": 1";
Mockito.when((String)restTemplate.postForObject(
                Mockito.any(String.class),
                Mockito.any(Map.class),
                Mockito.any(Class.class)
                )).thenReturn(testResponse);
Feature feature = new Feature();
feature.getfeature("http://mockValue");
}
```

I set breaking point at feature.getfeature("http://mockValue"). It still try to connect to the remote server. I don't want postForObject to connect to the http://mockValue. 
How should I mock the restTemplate to make postForObject not to connect to http://mockValue?

Comment: You are creating a new `RestTemplate` object in getfeature() method.

Comment: offtopic. You are mocking twice. with mock() and @Mock

Comment: You wont be able to to this since you are not using mock but actual impl. `new RestTemplate();`

Comment: please could you show any code example to test restTemplate, thx

Comment: why are you testing something that is not part of your code? You dont test RestTemplate but everything around it. The best would be mak your util non static, and provide rest template instance to use - it would be mock in your case.

Comment: This is exactly the purpose of *dependency injection*--you need to pass the mock as parameter to your `Feature` constructor (and use `RestOperations`; it's meant for this).

Comment: getFeature function is more complicated than I show above. I just want to mock the restTemplate.postForObject, and return a testResponse. So every time, restTemplate.postForObject be called in the Feature class, it will return testResponse. Does it have a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new `RestTemplate` object in `getfeature()` method. So, mocking `RestTemplate` has no effect. Either take `RestTemplate` as an argument in `getfeature()` method or take it as constructor argument in `Feature` class.

Then from the test class, you can mock RestTemplate and pass it like below:

```
Feature feature= new Feature(mockRestTemplate);
feature.getfeature(url);
```

Or

```
Feature feature = new Feature();
feature.getfeature(mockRestTemplate, url);
```

You have to make the necessary changes in the Feature class based on the decision.

Here is the running code sample:

**Main class:**

```
public class Feature {
    public static String getFeature(String url, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        return restTemplate.postForObject(url, "", String.class);
    }
}
```

**Test class:**

Notice the way the `RestTemplate` is mocked and then the response is mocked.

```
public class FeatureTest {
    @Test
    public void testFeature() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = Mockito.mock(RestTemplate.class);
        Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForObject(Mockito.any(String.class),
                Mockito.any(Object.class), Mockito.any(Class.class))).thenReturn("abc");
        System.out.println(Feature.getFeature("http://abc", restTemplate));
    }
}
```

The running code sample is also available at [github](https://github.com/fiveobjects/reference)

[Feature.java](https://github.com/fiveobjects/reference/blob/master/java/springboot/src/main/java/org/openapex/samples/springboot/template/Feature.java) and [FeatureTest.java](https://github.com/fiveobjects/reference/blob/master/java/springboot/src/test/java/FeatureTest.java)

Comment: i made a change on the Feature class and pass mockRestTemplate into the function, then the json return null instead of the testResponse

Comment: When you are mocking the respinse you are matching String,  Map and Class. But I see you are using String, String and Class. Can you use Mockito.anyObject () instread?

Comment: still return null

Comment: @lin I have added running code sample, please check.

Comment: instead of pass mockito.anyObject, I pass the xml, url and String.class in the test function and it works

Comment: Aren't you doing something like this? `Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForObject(Mockito.any(String.class),
                Mockito.any(Object.class), Mockito.any(Class.class))).thenReturn("abc")`. Can you please post the above line from your code? This can be done in multiple ways. The idea is argument type should match at runtime based on the types/values specified.

Comment: Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForObject(url,xml,String.class)).thenReturn("abc")

Comment: It's similar. You are trying to match exact URL, exact XML payload and String response type. There are many ways to match argument values. Depending on your various test scenarios you can match them in different ways.

Comment: @lin glad to know that your issue is resolved. Would you please accept this answer?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to constantly create a RestTemplate object.

You can create one and inject it into the class.

Then, in your unit test, create a mock RestTemplate and inject that.

Edit:
Concerning the static method.
Don't use a static method,
that is terrible.
If you are using Spring (or any other Dependency Injection framework)
just inject an instance of `Feature` where ever you want to make the rest call.

Also,
in the Spring world `Feature` is a service class.
Use the @Service annotation and make the method not static.

Comment: its a static method, you cannot use instance fields

Comment: Dont make its static then. Bad, hard to test design

Comment: Does have a way to not change the Feature class and still make the test done?

Comment: @lin try the above answer that i mentioned

Comment: @Pradeep I try the above answer, but the json return null, it doesn't return "Json"

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your code to make your unit test work atleast using Mockito or you have to use some other library like powermock to mock local object instantiation.

1) create a constructor that accepts RestTemplate as argument to inject your mock.

or

2) create some setter method to inject that RestTemplate.

one more way is to create another method where RestTemplate can be passed.

```
public String getStringAsJson(RestTemplate restTemplate, String url, String xml) {
     return  restTemplate.postForObject(url, xml, String.class);
}
```

then in your test:

```
RestTemplate mockRestTemplate = mock(RestTemplate.class);
when(restTemplate.postForObject(mockurl, mockUrl, mockXml)).thenReturn("Json");
feature.getStringAsJson(mockRestTemplate,mockUrl,mockXml);
```

Comment: When you say `Mockito.when(feature.getStringAsJson(mockRestTemplate, mockUrl, mockXml)).thenReturn("Json")` the original method under test (getStringAsJson) won't be executed at all and it will directly return "Json" as specified. The target method under test may have other business logic that we have to test. Here, the objective is to mock only RestTemplate methods to avoid actual HTTP calls over the network.

Comment: i didnt test but my idea is to inject through method argument

Comment: i see you answer too which seems to be what am explaining

Answer (score 0):

> how to junit test on restTemplate?

We test what it returns.
Currently your implementation does nothing itself, it simply  delegates to a `RestTemplate` and return its result.

The `fiveelements` answer describes the implementation (with broad accepted values as parameters) :

```
@Test 
public void testFeature() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = Mockito.mock(RestTemplate.class);
    Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForObject(Mockito.any(String.class),
            Mockito.any(Object.class), Mockito.any(Class.class))).thenReturn("abc");
    System.out.println(Feature.getFeature("http://abc", restTemplate));
}
```

That doesn't assert the actual behavior :  the URL could be erroneous, the body posted or the response could be wrong and so for... and this test will never detect that.  Finally, very important things could be wrong in this implementation and we could not detect that. The value of this kind of test is so weak.
Since this method doesn't perform itself logic, this is better suited for an integration test that could assert and catch much more thing/issues in the actual behavior :

```
@Test 
public void testFeature() {
    String actualFeature = Feature.getFeature("http://...");
    String expectedFeature = ...;
    Assertions.assertEquals(expectedFeature, actualFeature);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use **PowerMockito** then you can do like following:

*No code change needed here for Feature class then you can use this directly if PowerMockito lib available in prj*

```
RestTemplate mockedRestTemplate = PowerMockito.mock(RestTemplate.class);
PowerMockito.whenNew(RestTemplate.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockedRestTemplate);
```